# Django "Duplicate" ModelForm

Tags: django, duplicates, modelform

I'm wondering if there is a simple way of creating a "duplicate" ModelForm in Django - i.e. a form that is prefilled with the content of an existing model instance (excepting certain fields, such as those that are unique), but creates a new instance when saved.

I was thinking along the lines of supplying an instance to a ModelForm so that the data is prefilled as with an "edit" form, then setting the instance to None before saving, but this gives a "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pk'" error when calling .save() on the form. It seems the act of supplying an instance when constructing the form creates some dependency on it being there at the end.

I have had trouble finding a solution to this problem, but I can't imagine a "duplicate" form being too unique, so maybe I am missing something simple?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a workable solution, OP?

Comment: This was a while (and several versions of Django) ago, and didn't end up being a feature we implemented. So no, I never did settle on a solution. While [@Pydev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3606911/405174) apparently didn't work for me at the time, it may be a different story in a newer version of Django. However, it also carries the risk of copying _too much_, since you're starting from a fully-populated model instance. Then again, maybe that's behaviour you want.

Comment: If I were to attempt it again today, I'd probably try something along the lines of [@Manoj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3606332/405174). The form knows the fields it contains, so a generic solution that grabs those fields off a given instance and uses them to populate `initial` shouldn't be too hard. Maybe as a factory classmethod, e.g. `MyForm.as_duplicate(data, instance)`?

Comment: Thanks for following up! I wound up doing something very similar to what you've described here. A class method on the model which handles the duplication and a subclassed version of my WidgetUpdateView which uses the duplicate method to swap in the new instance in `form_valid`.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a way to fill in the initial values for the fields in the form. The best way to accomplish this would be to create a dictionary of initial values (keyed by field name) from an existing instance and supply this to the form.

Something like this:

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

# Inside view:
address = Address.object.get(**conditions)
initial = dict()
for field in ('state', 'zipcode'): # Assuming these are the fields you want to pre-fill
    initial[field] = getattr(address, field)

form = AddressForm(initial = initial)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Address

# Inside view:
address = Address.object.get(pk=<your-id>)
address.pk = None # that's the trick, after form save new object will be created
form = AddressForm(instance=address)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as altering the pk property does not seem to alter the actual primary key field ('id' in my case). Thus, the ModelForm still overwrites the existing object as opposed to creating a new one.

Comment: I believe that you need to save the model after setting the pk to None and before passing into the form.  I just handle this within the view, so right before saving the form, you want to do this swap (form.instance.pk = None; form.instance.save())